# Using A Controller in a Custom Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications

I've been following along with a codeschool Angular tutorial and my app works fine until adding this custom directive:

```
// Breaks here 
app.directive('reviewForm', function() {
   return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'partials/review-form.html',
        replace: true,
        controller: function() {
            this.showForm: false;
        },
        controllerAs: 'reviewFormCtrl',

    }
})
```

And here is the error I receive via console.log:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled 
the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module
ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Comment: What is the exact problem? What error shows up in console log?

Comment: Sorry, could've included originally. Here is the error I recieve:  Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: your controller function has wrong syntax. 

`this.showForm : false` should be `this.showForm = false`

Comment: @Calrocks good to hear that, you are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is spelling mistake, your module name is myApp, and in your code you wrote:

```
app.directive('reviewForm', function() {......
```

it should be myApp.directive , like this:

```
myApp.directive('reviewForm', function() {
   return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'partials/review-form.html',
        replace: true,
        controller: function() {
            this.showForm: false;
        },
        controllerAs: 'reviewFormCtrl',

    }
})
```

if it did not work, check the spelling of your module name.